# Cygwin 32 faster than Cygwin 64? High grep memory usage

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cygwin

I am grepping large files. When I run the command on Cygwin32, it is completed in 46 seconds. However, when I run the same command on Cygwin64, the memory use just climbs and eventually the memory is exhausted after 30-40 minutes.

Shouldn't Cygwin64 be faster than Cygwin32?

Here's a couple things I already tried:

- Avoid caching with fresh file names
- Reinstalling Cygwin64 from new mirror site (to avoid incomplete package)

I would like to upgrade to Cygwin64 to work with the updated split command options. However, I need grep to work properly too.

Please let me know if you have an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the 64bit implementation. A memory leak.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking memory leak too. It just climbs from .5 GB to 3.8+ GB and stops as my system has 4.0 GB of RAM. Think I should just keep trying different packages?

Comment: Or compile it yourself, that should be the best match to you system. However it might also be that there really is a bug in the code itself. You'd have to debug that, using `valgrind` for example. Oh, also take a look at their bug tracker and forum, maybe that issue is known and there is a workaround or fix.

Comment: Kind of a side issue really, but... why would you expect the 64-bit version to be faster than the 32-bit version? I can't fathom any reason why that would be so. If anything, 64-bit versions will be larger due to 64-bit pointers rather than 32-bit pointers.  As a result, I'd expect more cache line evictions under 64-bit (== slower). The major advantage of 64-bit is the size of the address space, but I can't see how that would make a difference for grep.

Comment: @GilHamilton thanks for the information. I was thinking that 64 would have more up to date packages and better memory utilization, leading to improved speed and performance. I guess that is not the case? Even so, something is going on with Grep in Cygwin64 because it should be able to carry out commands that Cygwin32 does.

Comment: Compiling for 64-bit can theoretically use the full capabilities of 64-bit CPU, meaning if your code does some fancy math, it might be faster. In many cases, that will only happen if the code explicitly uses the 64-bit capabilities, which is true only for some specialized applications. For generic code, the compiler might do some optimizations but most likely it can give only modest improvements in speed, if any at all.
64-bit can address more memory (32-bit pointers can address 4 Gb at most) - this won't give any improvement to common UNIX tools in question.